# Attach file to issue in GitHub via API

Tags: redmine, github-api

My requirement is to migrate issues from Redmine to GitHub issue tracker.
I exported Redmine issues to a csv file. Using GitHub issue api I am able to create issues in github along with labels.

But I also need to attach file while creating issue, using GitHub REST apis.
Is it possible to attach files while creating issue in github via API?

If anybody knows the solution for this please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible to attach files to issues via the GitHub API.

Comment: Sir, is there any other solution for this. I have around 2000 issues in redmine and each issue has one file attached to it. It will require lot of manual effort. Please suggest if we can do it by some other way.

Comment: No, the GitHub API just doesn't support this currently.

Comment: @ayogi You probably can hack it using PhantomJS and simulating the user behavior on the page, but not using the API.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But can you provide more detail description about this.